# How to downgrade Entity framework from 6 to 5?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm creating a Asp.Net MVC project using VS2013 and added hottowel (2.0.1) using nuget. However, the breeze doesn't work with Entity Framework 6.

How to downgrade the Entity Framework 6 of the created project to EF5?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

in the nuget package console for your project (select it in the dropdown) type:

```
Uninstall-package EntityFramework
Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0
```

Comment: I got the following error when uninstalling `
Uninstall-Package : Unable to uninstall 'EntityFramework 6.0.0-rc1' because 'Breeze.Server.WebApi.EF 1.4.6, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 1.0.0-rc1' depend on it.`.

Comment: You could try adding a -force to the end of the uninstall command. This will mean it will ignore dependancies

Comment: However Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework relies on EF 6 which means that you (probably) cant downgrade if you want that package. If you think you can get away with it you could use a binding redirect to force Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework to use the EF5

Comment: Yes, I got the Identity EF error. The site need to login using Facebook.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 have you tried a binding redirect from 5->6 this may get your other library that uses EF 5 working. If not unfortunatly you are in a situation where you have conflicting versioning and there may not be a sensible way of getting around it without removing one of the packages you are wanting to use.

Comment: Or is it possible to replace `Breeze Server (obsolete)`, `Breeze Client and Server (obsolte)` and `Breeze Server (obsolete) - for Legacy ASP.NET Web API and Entity Framework 5` in hottowel with new version of breeze which support EF6 using nuget?

Comment: note: still had to manually update the web.config. changed Version=6.0.0.0 to Version 5.0.0.0 under the entity framework config section.

Comment: I had to do the same to manually remove the dependent assembly from app.config in my test project

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework also moves the `__MigrationHistory` table from System Tables to user tables. When I tried to run my application after rollback it wouldn't work, so I had to move the `__MigrationHistory` back to the system tables with:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject __MigrationHistory;
```

When I did upgrade to EntityFramework 6 I had to add an empty migration (unfortunately I do not remember the reason, but I guess it complained about updating the database or similar). I also had to remove that empty migration. Since this was a completely empty migration I guess this is safe to do, **I do not know about migrations that actually change the database**. However, they might not complain when running the program.

```
delete from dbo.__MigrationHistory where MigrationId = 'myEmptyMigration';
```

Then I deleted the empty migrationfile from my project which resolved my problems.

Answer (score 1):

The Breeze packages marked with "(obsolete)" are intended for use with EF5 and WebApi.  The 'current' packages ( those not marked with obsolete) are all intended for WebApi2 and EF6.  There is no option currently to mix and match EF5 with WebApi2.  If this is important please add this to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post with an Answer already but thought I'd add this little nugget.

If you have many projects using Entity Framework and want to downgrade all of them, first change one of the projects manually, then refresh the package description page and you will get Consolidate as an Action. Select this, then select version 5.0.0 and this will let you downgrade all projects to 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

for downgrading, you should see an option in nuget package manager under the installed tab for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.
click on that and the details menu directly to the right should match the version you are on. From there you can click the drop down menu and select a prior version.

here is the regular terminal version for ef core for your tool if you need it for some reason. It should be backwards compatable though

```
dotnet tool uninstall dotnet-ef -g

dotnet tool install dotnet-ef --version X.Y.Z -g
```

Answer (score -2):

on **Package Manager Console** write

PM> Uninstall-package `EntityFramework`

PM> Install-Package `EntityFramework` -version `5.0.0`

Comment: This simply restates the most upvoted/accepted answer.