# Error generating model using EF 6: "The name 'X' does not exist in the current context Y is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I'm exploring Entity Framework and I'm having some trouble when I try to generate a model using the EF 6 EntityObject Generator template. Once the template completes its operation I get a bunch of errors in the error list. Here are four of the errors:

> The name 'TemplateMetadata' does not exist in the current context
> 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EnumType' is inaccessible due to its protection level
> 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EnumType' does not contain a definition for 'UnderlyingType' and no extension method 'UnderlyingType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EnumType' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating32E3A8132CB3A5BCD6B75A5C1B94668D.GeneratedTextTransformation.MetadataConstants' does not contain a definition for 'TT_TEMPLATE_VERSION'

According to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19239140/does-entity-framework-6-support-net-4-0) `EF 6` will work with `.NET 4`, but according to [this CodePlex post](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1822), `EF 6` doesn't support `.NET 4` so as a complete beginner to EF, I'm a bit confused.

If I cannot use `EF 6`, how can I safely downgrade my project to `EF 5`?

Comment: To downgrade to EF 5 I followed [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282678/how-to-downgrade-entity-framework-from-6-to-5)

Comment: Why do you use the EntityObject template instead of the DbContext one that is the default and built-in VS2013? (also why aren't you using .NET Framework 4.5?)

Comment: So right now you are running .NET 4.0, EF 5.0 in VS2010? Once you downgraded, did you have the same issue?

Comment: @Termato, yes, I'm using .net 4 EF 5 and VS2010, once I downgraded to EF 5 I didn't get any error messages and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: You should answer your own question :) and then mark it as answered.