# How to downgrade from EF6 to EF5

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I have a windows application which used to use EF 5 Code first.

This application is being used by 100+ clients.

Recently, I upgraded EF5 to EF6.

The upgrade is deployed to 100 clients.

The migration history table of EF5 was also upgraded to EF6, which introduced a new primary key column 'ContextKey'.

Now I want to revert EF6 to EF5.

I have a script to drop 'ContextKey' from the migration table.

But I can not manually execute to 100+ clients.

What would be the best way to downgrade from EF6 to EF5?

Comment: why do you want to go back? which issue do you have in EF6? Try to solve this instead of going back

Comment: Agree with magicandre. Why not just deal with the problem ContextKey presents? It is a fairly simple concept. You write a single line script to set the ContextKey to match your settings. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn948104.aspx). If you still feel the need to downgrade, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282678/how-to-downgrade-entity-framework-from-6-to-5).